# x.__proto__ == X.prototype is not always same as x instanceof X in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototypal-inheritance

I know that one should not use `__proto__` directly in the code, but just out of curiosity I was playing around with this in node.  I was under the impression that if `x.__proto__ == X.prototype` then it means `x instanceof X` will yield `true` until I hit this code with primitive values.

```
> (2).__proto__ ==  Number.prototype
true
> 2 instanceof Number
false
> (2) instanceof Number
false


> "abc".__proto__ == String.prototype
true
> "abc" instanceof String
false
> ("abc") instanceof String
false
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`instanceof` will always yield `false` if the left-hand side is not an object (see [Step 3 here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ordinaryhasinstance)).

The reason `(2).__proto__ == Number.prototype` is true is that when you apply a property accessor to a primitive (in this case, `.__proto__`), a temporary object with the same underlying primitive value is created and used.

So the thing you're getting the `__proto__` property from isn't the same thing you're using in your `instanceof` cases, because it isn't a primitive. Your test cases would more accurately be:

```
> (2).__proto__ == Number.prototype
true
> new Number(2) instanceof Number
true
```

---

> I was under the impression that if `x.__proto__ == X.prototype` then it means `x instanceof X` will yield `true`

That's true as far as it goes (or would be if you used `===`, for a fairly obscure reason<sup>1</sup>), but note that the converse is not true: If `x instanceof X` is true, that doesn't necessarily mean `x.__proto__ == X.prototype` will be true, for a couple of reasons:

1. It could be that you need to use `x.__proto__.__proto__`, or `x.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__`, or... :-)
2. `x.__proto__` may well be `undefined`. For instance, it is if you create `x` like this: `x = Object.create(null)`. The reason is that the `__proto__` property accessor is provided by `Object.prototype`, but if you create an object that doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`, it doesn't have the `__proto__` property accessor (on a compliant implementation). This is one reason to use `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)` instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> Fairly obscure reason: If `x` was created via `Object.create(null)` (or using any prototype that doesn't trace back to `Object.prototype`) and thus doesn't have the `__proto__` property accessor, and `X.prototype` is `null`, `x.__proto__ == X.prototype` would be `true` even though they could well be completely and utterly unrelated, since `x.__proto__` would be `undefined` and `undefined == null` is true. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Primitive values are not objects, and thus are not instances of any constructor.

Your checks will work if you coerce the values to objects:

```js
console.log(Object(2) instanceof Number); // true
console.log(Object("abc") instanceof String); // true
console.log(Object(true) instanceof Boolean); // true
console.log(Object(Symbol()) instanceof Symbol); // true
```